# MySQL Simplify This Query?

Tags: mysql, database, reporting, google-visualization, simplify

I've been writing MySQL queries for a long time, but I totally feel like a newbie when it comes to this and I just can't seem to figure out how to simplify this query.  Basically **I'm just trying to generate a comma delimited list of revenue** from our database that eventually gets plugged into google charts.  I have to make one for "the past 31 days" also, so I'm kinda screwed unless I figured out how to simplify this.

My Database columns in my table are...

> - time: When the order came in int() (UNIX timestamp format)
> - price: How much the order was for decimal(10,2)

```
SELECT
 CONCAT(
 (SELECT SUM(price) FROM orders WHERE time < (UNIX_TIMESTAMP() - (6 * 86400)) AND time > (UNIX_TIMESTAMP() - (7 * 86400))),
 ',',
 (SELECT SUM(price) FROM orders WHERE time < (UNIX_TIMESTAMP() - (5 * 86400)) AND time > (UNIX_TIMESTAMP() - (6 * 86400))),
 ',',
 (SELECT SUM(price) FROM orders WHERE time < (UNIX_TIMESTAMP() - (4 * 86400)) AND time > (UNIX_TIMESTAMP() - (5 * 86400))),
 ',',
 (SELECT SUM(price) FROM orders WHERE time < (UNIX_TIMESTAMP() - (3 * 86400)) AND time > (UNIX_TIMESTAMP() - (4 * 86400))),
 ',',
 (SELECT SUM(price) FROM orders WHERE time < (UNIX_TIMESTAMP() - (2 * 86400)) AND time > (UNIX_TIMESTAMP() - (3 * 86400))),
 ',',
 (SELECT SUM(price) FROM orders WHERE time < (UNIX_TIMESTAMP() - 86400) AND time > (UNIX_TIMESTAMP() - (2* 86400)) ),
 ',',
 (SELECT SUM(price) FROM orders WHERE time > (UNIX_TIMESTAMP() - 86400))
 ) as chart_rev 
FROM orders_basic
LIMIT 0,1
```

If possible, I need it in 24 hour increments like this.

As always, any help is much appreciated.  Thanks!

**SOLUTION**

*Please note: Look carefully at your results, they may be there, just in the wrong order, if so, reverse your sorting.*

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(total_sum) AS sum_list FROM
(
    SELECT
        FLOOR((UNIX_TIMESTAMP() - time) / 86400) AS date,
        SUM(price) AS total_sum
    FROM
        orders_basic
    WHERE
        is_testorder < 1
          AND FROM_UNIXTIME(time) > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 WEEK)
    GROUP BY
        date
) AS s
```

Comment: First I would try incorporating [`DATE_ADD()` and `INTERVAL`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-add) which is more readable.  Then I would try a [`GROUP_CONCAT()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) over the month range and group by the day number.

Comment: Thanks for showing us what you've tried, however it would be easier if you showed us the schema and your desired output.

Comment: @Marcus Adams, I did explain the schema and say what my desired output is.  I have formatted it more clearly for you.  There are only 2 columns.  An example of what I want would be: 1.01,3,2,4.23

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this maybe?

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(total_sum) AS sum_list FROM
(
    SELECT
        DATE(FROM_UNIXTIME(time)) AS date,
        SUM(price) AS total_sum
    FROM
        orders
    WHERE
        FROM_UNIXTIME(time) > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH)
    GROUP BY
        date
) AS s
```

This should give you a comma separated list of last month sale sums. But it will group on the date, not 24 hour increments (so cutoff will be midnight, according to the `time` column).

Comment: This is very helpful Silver.  Thanks!  I will award you the answer if someone doesn't get me a version in 24 hour increments prior to me figuring it out.

Comment: @PolishHurricane Try replacing `DATE(FROM_UNIXTIME(time)) AS date` with `FLOOR((UNIX_TIMESTAMP() - time) / 86400) AS date` (keep the comma at the end). It's a bit messy, but this should give you the data in 24-hour increments from the moment it is run instead, up to 1 month backwards (so you may get 32 entries, change `INTERVAL 1 MONTH` accordingly if that's a problem).

Comment: Yeah that's a good try, but it still fails :(  I'm still trying to figure it out.  I think I need to modify the WHERE or GROUPing.

Comment: How is it failing? I see I changed the table name in the query, for example, from testing it on one of my own tables. It seems to work here, unless I've misunderstood what you are looking for.

Comment: Oh apologies, I read the data wrong, you're a genius.  I'm all set, thanks!